# Reprogramming computer for Dodge Ram Van 1999

Tags: dodge, computer, reprogram

I had a problem my old computer on my 1999 Dodge Ram Van and have now acquired a new one, however the one I have acquired has not been programmed for my van. My mechanic tried to program it by connecting his laptop to the van and using a ‘delphi’ software but the new computer doesn’t show up. Should we be using a different software? Do we need extra hardware? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Louis

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score -1):

You will probably have to go to a dealer and use dealer level software - a generic garage tool may not have complete write capability to install the program from scratch.

Comment: Good luck downvoter, keep going - I have posted many answers for the benefit of others.... Perhaps you could make the effort to do the same...